# Copy column from 1 table to the other

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to transfer a column of data from one table to the other.
e.g

```
Table 1 : 
ID, NAME, ADDRESS
```

ID and NAME currently have data in it. ADDRESS is empty.

```
TABLE2 : 
ADDRESS
```

I would like to copy the whole column of ADDRESS data from table 2 and insert into table 1 together with the existing data in ID and name.

I cannot use insert command as it will only start inserting from the end of the data in table1.

Please help.

Comment: How will you know which data goes into which row of table1? Is there a relation?

Comment: I don't see any way of doing this _using_ INSERT, let alone not using it.

Comment: @GurV The data order in table 1 matches the data in table 2. Therefore we just have to insert it directly. It is just that it is separated into 2 tables.

Comment: @Tim Biegelesien, Yes, I am asking if there is any way to do it.

Comment: The data order with regard to which column?

Comment: @user7609786 - In RDBMS, a table is a unordered set of rows. You will need to specify a column or set of columns which define the exact order.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Data order meaning if we just insert the ADDRESS column from table2 into table1 directly, the address will match the id and name as the order is already correct.

Comment: OK, but as @GurV mentioned, you need to be able to articulate an `ORDER BY` which can produce the current "correct" ordering.  Without that, I'm afraid we can't give you a query.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Oh no. I see. I do not have any order by to produce the current ordering x.x Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user7609786 All hope isn't lost.  Postgres has a `ROW_NUMBER()` function which would be very helpful here _if_ you had a column to use for the ordering you want.  Internally, recognize that there is _no_ ordering, and what you are seeing could be random.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Oh ! thanks! I will research on the row_number (:

Answer (score 0):

Using row_number:

step1 : copy columns of both table with new column for row number to temporary table

step2  : Join both temporary tables and update the temporary table with address

step3 : Join the temporary table with original table and update the address

For the example which is mentioned in the question, query will be as below:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS, row_number() over (order by(select 1)) rnum
INTO #tempTable1
FROM Table1

SELECT ADDRESS, row_number() over (order by(select 1)) rnum
INTO #tempTable2
FROM Table2

update t1
set t1.ADDRESS = t2.ADDRESS
from #tempTable1 t1
join #tempTable2 t2
on t1.rnum = t2.rnum

update t1
set t1.ADDRESS = t2.ADDRESS
from Table1 t1
join #tempTable1 t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
```